# Trying to tokenize a string by spaces and quotes

Tags: c, string, pointers

So I've been working on this for a little bit and I'm having some weird problems. The end goal is to split up an input string by both whitespace and quotes (i.e. this "is a" very "very complex" example goes to {this, is a, very, very complex, example). Right now it seems to split it all up correctly with the exception of the first string.

Here it is (buff is being passed in with a value from getline):

```
char **tokens = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));
char *temp;
int count = 0;
int prev = 0;
// Get tokens
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(command) && running; i++) {
    if (i > prev && strncmp((buff + i), " ", 1) == 0) {
        temp = (char **)realloc(tokens, (sizeof(char)) * WORD_SIZE * (++count));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in parsing: ran out of memory\n");
            running = false;
            free(tokens);
        }
        else {
            tokens = temp;
            *(temp) = (buff + i);
            strncpy(*(temp), "\0", 1);
            temp = tokens + WORD_SIZE * (count - 1);
            *(temp) = buff+prev;
            prev = i+1;
        }
    }
    else if (strncmp((buff + i), "\"", 1) == 0) {
        *(temp) = (buff + i);
            strncpy(*(temp), "\0", 1);
        i++;
        prev = i;
        for (; strncmp((buff + i), "\"", 1) != 0; i++) { }
        temp = (char **)realloc(tokens, (sizeof(char)) * WORD_SIZE * (++count));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in parsing: ran out of memory\n");
            running = false;
            free(tokens);
        }
        else {
            tokens = temp;
            *(temp) = (buff + i);
            strncpy(*(temp), "\0", 1);
            temp = tokens + WORD_SIZE * (count - 1);
            *(temp) = buff+prev;
            prev = i+1;
        }
    }
    else if (strncmp((buff + i), "\0", 1) == 0) {
        temp = (char **)realloc(tokens, (sizeof(char)) * WORD_SIZE * (++count));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in parsing: ran out of memory\n");
            running = false;
            free(tokens);
        }
        else {
            tokens = temp;
            temp = tokens + WORD_SIZE * (count - 1);
            *(temp) = buff+prev;
            prev = i+1;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     printf("\t%i: %s\n", i, *tokens + sizeof(char) * WORD_SIZE * i);
```

Right now if I input "this is a test" (no quotes) I get:
0:
1: is
2: a
3: test

Quotes are a little more messed up, for "this \"is a\" very \"very complex\" test" I get:
0:
1: is a
2:
3: very complex
4:  test

Comment: First obsn. (but --probably-- unrelated to your issue): you need to allocate `sizeof(char *)` in `char **tokens = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));`, not `sizeof(char)` (which is usually '1'). (Also, no need to cast `malloc` in C.)

Comment: @Jongware Yea, I went ahead and changed it but the pointer is realloc-ed before every token is added (including the first time) so the malloc is really just a formality, it doesn't really matter the initial size.

Comment: Good catch @Jongware.  Actually `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code starting with the basic approach.  Are you interested in a new code that is of higher quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a totally new write from scratch, as that was easier to rewrite your own code (apologies if that was not your intention). A few notes:

1. No need to test for previous `malloc`s. You can safely `realloc` a NULL pointer.
2. `if (strncmp((buff + i), "\"", 1) == 0)` -- you can test `buff[i]` immediately.
3. Why all that `prev` shuffling? :) It's enough to loop *once* over your string.
4. I left the `temp` test for successfully `realloc` in because you had it as well. It's actually unnecessary in my code, as it merely exits `main`.
5. added: the character `"` also introduces a new 'word' when not preceded by a space.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char **tokens = NULL;
    int i, count = 0, strcount;
    char **temp, *iterate;

    char *input = "this \"is a\" very \"very complex\" test";

    iterate = input;

    if (iterate)
    {
        while (*iterate)
        {
            while (*iterate == ' ')
                iterate++;

            if (!*iterate)
                break;

            temp = realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *) * (count+1));
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error in parsing: ran out of memory\n");
                return -1;
            }
            tokens = temp;

            if (*iterate == '\"')
            {
                iterate++;
                strcount = 0;
                while (iterate[strcount] && iterate[strcount] != '\"')
                    strcount++;
                tokens[count] = malloc(strcount+1);
                strncpy (tokens[count], iterate, strcount);
                tokens[count][strcount] = 0;
                count++;
                iterate += strcount;
                if (*iterate == '\"')
                    iterate++;
            } else
            {
                strcount = 0;
                while (iterate[strcount] && iterate[strcount] != ' ' && iterate[strcount] != '\"')
                    strcount++;
                tokens[count] = malloc(strcount+1);
                strncpy (tokens[count], iterate, strcount);
                tokens[count][strcount] = 0;
                count++;
                iterate += strcount;
            }
        } while (*iterate);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("\t%i: %s\n", i, tokens[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output for `this "is a" very "very complex" test`:

```
0: this
1: is a
2: very
3: very complex
4: test
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have the best professor, so about 95% my knowledge of C comes from looking things up myself. Which means there are a lot of things I miss, such as the fact you can index pointers.

Comment: @Michael: in that case, +1 for the shown effort! At least it was a valiant try.

Comment: Yea, I really don't like to ask for help on non-conceptual problems, but I felt like I was just going about things wrong. I know enough to realize how ugly my code was getting as I modified it.

Answer (score 3):

You said an alternative code would be okay.  Simple string parsing algorithms are almost always easier and produce more maintainable code if you use a Deterministic Finite Automaton model to think about them.  There are many free references for DFAs on the web.

Here's a DFA that solves your problem.

[image: dfa]

The meaning of [any] is "all else".  In other words, if no other transition matches, take this one.  It becomes the `default` case in a C `switch`.  The meaning of [eos] is "end of string" or the null character.

Note that the DFA lets you be systematic about all cases, for example a quote appearing while in the middle of a word.  Here I treated this as the end of the current word and beginning of a new quoted one.  If the spec changes, the DFA is quite easy to change and the changes translate to code with no hard thinking.

All that remains is to add "action code" to capture the token starts and overwrite null terminators at the obvious places.  In C, we have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **tokenize(char *str, int *n_tokens_rtn)
{
  // State of the DFA.
  enum { Error = -1, Start, InQuoted, InWord } state = Start;

  // String pointer and current character
  int cp = 0;

#define CURRENT_CHAR (str[cp])
#define ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR do { ++cp; } while (0)
#define MARK_END_OF_TOKEN do { str[cp] = '\0'; } while (0)

  // Token pointer and buffer. Allocate biggest possible and shrink at end.
  int tp = 0;
  char **tokens = safe_malloc((1 + strlen(str) / 2) * sizeof *tokens);

#define SAVE_TOKEN do { tokens[tp++] = &str[cp]; } while (0)

  // Each iteration is one DFA transition.
  for (;;) {
    switch (state) {
    case Start:
      switch (CURRENT_CHAR) {
      case '\0':
        goto done_scanning;

      case ' ': case '\t': case '\n':
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        break;

      case '"':
        state = InQuoted;
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        SAVE_TOKEN;
        break;

      default:
        state = InWord;
        SAVE_TOKEN;
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case InQuoted:
      switch (CURRENT_CHAR) {
      case '\0':
        state = Error; // Missing close quote.
        break;

      case '"':
        state = Start;
        MARK_END_OF_TOKEN;
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        break;

      default:
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case InWord:
      switch (CURRENT_CHAR) {

      case '\0':
        goto done_scanning;

      case ' ': case '\t': case '\n':
        state = Start;
        MARK_END_OF_TOKEN;
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        break;

      case '"': // Word ended in quote, not space.
        state = InQuoted;
        MARK_END_OF_TOKEN;
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        SAVE_TOKEN;
        break;

      default:
        ADVANCE_TO_NEXT_CHAR;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case Error:
      fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error.\n");
      goto done_scanning;
    }
  }

 done_scanning:
  // Return number of tokens if caller is interested.
  if (n_tokens_rtn) *n_tokens_rtn = tp;

  // Append a null terminator for good measure.
  tokens[tp++] = NULL;

  // Trim the returned value to the right size.
  return realloc(tokens, tp * sizeof *tokens);
}

int main(void)
{
  char str[] = "this \"is a\" very \"very complex\" example";
  char **tokens = tokenize(str, NULL);
  for (int i = 0; tokens[i]; i++)
    printf("%s\n", tokens[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From state InQuoted, a `"` should probably go to InWord, rather than Start (at least if you want shell-like handling of mixed quoted/unquoted stuff -- something like `ab"c d"ef` is the single token `abc def`).

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks. I treated a non-quote quote boundary and vice-versa as a token separator. He didn't specify. The nice thing about the DFA is that it more-or-less forces you to decide explicitly, which ad hoc code usually doesn't.

Comment: +1 for the DFA. In addition to appreciating the problem-solving vs implementation aspect I'm also in a CS Theory class, so it's nice to see them in action.

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  It's amazing how often a DFA will simplify a problem: scanning, user interfaces, interrupt processing, marshaling, ...

Answer (score 0):

This appears like a relatively simple problem, so rather than write a full parser, I wrote up a solution using the standard C library to do the heavy lifting. Judge for yourself if this solution is appealing. There are probably ways to improve on what I've done to make the code a bit clearer as well, I'll leave that as an exercise for anyone so inclined.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input_string[] = "this \"is a\" very \"very complex\" test";
    char **tokens = NULL;
    int token_count = 0;
    char *ptr = input_string;
    int i;
    char *next_ptr = ptr;

    while (*ptr && next_ptr)
    {
        while (*ptr == ' ') ptr++;
        tokens = realloc(tokens, ++token_count * sizeof(char *));
        if (tokens == NULL)
            return -1;
        if (*ptr == '"')
            next_ptr = strchr(ptr+1, '"');
        else
            next_ptr = strpbrk(ptr, " \"");
        if (next_ptr)
        {
            tokens[token_count-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (next_ptr - (ptr+(*ptr=='"'))) + 1);
            if (tokens[token_count-1] == NULL)
                return -1;
            strncpy(tokens[token_count-1], (ptr+(*ptr=='"')), next_ptr - (ptr+(*ptr=='"')));
            tokens[token_count-1][next_ptr - (ptr+(*ptr=='"'))] = 0;
            ptr = next_ptr + (*ptr=='"');
        }
        else
            tokens[token_count-1] = strdup(ptr+(*ptr=='"'));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < token_count; ++i)
        printf("[%d]: %s\n", i, tokens[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[0]: this
[1]: is a
[2]: very
[3]: very complex
[4]: test
```